# Assistance with MDX and comparing columns

Tags: mdx

I have 5 columns Temp, height, weight, pulse and site
I want to figure out which sites are reporting the same information.  For example, Sites 1 and 2 have the same values for pulse...I'm looking for either an expression that would represent this, any suggestions?

Ive tried 
     If([PULSE Beats/Min]=[PULSE Beats/Min],"Duplicate",[PULSE Beats/Min])

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples, which are notated with parentheses and members from different hierarchies (which are e. g. site and measures) separated by commas, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487118.aspx).

```
IIf(([Measures].[PULSE Beats/Min], [Site].[Site 1]) = ([Measures].[PULSE Beats/Min], [Site].[Site 1]),
    "Duplicate",
    [PULSE Beats/Min]
   )
```

Comment: Thanks for you help...When I use the above expression, It errors out to. Expected ')' at line 1 character 32 but found ','

Comment: How exactly are the site hierarchy, and the site members named? Could you paste the exact expression that you entered?